# How to use Chrome extension to upload photos to Ebay listing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, ebay-api, photo-upload

I am writing a Chrome extension that will take a file full of photos and automatically upload them to an eBay listing.  I'm pretty much a newbie at Javascript/Chrome Extensions.

My idea is to have an

```
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
```

which will handle the photos and then communicate with eBay's photo upload section, which looks like this:

**ebay photo upload section :**
[image: ebay photo upload section]

Here is the code of the HTML element of the first box which has the "add photos" button:

```
<input class="upl-fileInp" type="file" name="d" value="" aria-label="Add photos" multiple="" tabindex="0" id="upl-21583221343545">
```

I'm not sure exactly how to approach this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here is a photo of the GUI for the Chrome Extension:
[Chrome Extension GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiSPK.jpg)

Comment: Where are the photos located?

Comment: In a directory on my local system.  Running Windows 10

Comment: What part of the process do you want to automate exactly? Clicking add photos and selecting the photos? In that case how will the extension know which photos to select? BTW your question is tagged with "ebay-api", have you tried using the api instead? https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/additem.html

Comment: Well, so far, I have my chrome extension working so that it just injects a series of JS commands.  Here would be a typical list of commands:

Comment: document.getElementById('editpane_title').value = 'QO260 Square D Circuit Breaker (Lot of 2)';
document.getElementById('editpane_skuNumber').value = 'inventoryloc: 255';
document.getElementById('storeCat').value = '11454932';
document.getElementById('itemCondition').value = 2500;
document.getElementById('editpane_condDesc').value = 'Cleaned and tested.  Works great! Please see photos!  Items shipped as pictured.';
document.getElementById('descDiv').getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = 'QO260 Square D Circuit Breaker';

Comment: These commands just get page elements and then set their values to the strings that I want the form fields to hold.  I guess my question is:  is there a way to have a JS command to reference the "add photos" element on the page and then set its "value" to a picture that was uploaded to the Chrome Extension?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the extension UI

Comment: What you want does not seem to be possible for security reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html
You really should just use the API to automate adding items, I don't see why you would do this hacky thing of filling the page if they provide a dedicated API.